# change the color of a php generated div using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to build a small list where users can indicate their favorite theme.

So, basically, when the user clicks on a div the background color (currently gray) changes to another color (green). When he clicks another time the background color has to change back to gray. I was able to change the color of the divs, but it also changed the color of the divs in front of him. The indicated divs (green) should be saved in my database.

My PHP code:

```
<?php
    while($Keuzescherm= $allGenres->fetch_assoc())
    {echo "<div class='keuzeDiv' id='".$Keuzescherm['Genrenaam'] ."'>" . $Keuzescherm['Genrenaam']."</>";}
?>
```

I'm not sure about the Javascript. But I'm guessing you need to use `getElementById()`. At the moment I'm using this:

```
$(".keuzeDiv").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("green");
});
```

and the CSS:

```
.keuzeDiv {
    background-color:#dddddd; 
    padding-top:5%;
    color: black;
}
```

So my question is: **how can I change the background color of the indicated div and save those divs in my database?**

Comment: Please post the JS code you've written so far, thanks.

Comment: Since JS is client side - there's no point in posting the PHP code. You should post the generated HTML including the JS code. Only after you get this part done, you should consider changing the PHP code that generates the JS/HTML

Comment: Making the question bold doesn't change the fact that we need to see your code!  ;)

Comment: changing the background colour means monitoring click events. Saving the new settings means using an AJAX call.  Have a look at the jQuery (http://jquery.com/) library. It helps make both those things easier.

Comment: @DerekHenderson: the OP didn't add the bold. Another editor did.

Comment: Jquery -> ajax -> php -> mysql -> Jquery

Basically you would use the jquery to wait on a click event, then have the ajax submit to the php/mysql to retrieve what the next color would be, and then jquery again to change that color.

Comment: i didnt make the question bold. I didnt post the JS code since it was wrong. Instead of changed the background color of the indicated div, it changed the bg color of the previousd divs too

Comment: I'm not a php developer but is the ";" between the class attr and the id attr a typo?

Comment: now the question is do you want to know how to select the div or how to set the bgcolor of the div?

Comment: @GertjanVanhove, of course the code is wrong or you wouldn't have to post a question.  Thing is, we can't really help you without seeing it.  We're not here to judge you on the quality of your js code.  Instead, we can see where you have made a mistake and help you fix it.

Comment: I've added the JS code

Comment: how about the css for this green class youre toggling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your PHP code.  You do not correctly close each DIV.

Change

```
{echo "<div class='keuzeDiv' id='".$Keuzescherm['Genrenaam'] ."'>" . $Keuzescherm['Genrenaam']."</>";}
```

(which produces `<div>...</>`)

to

```
{echo "<div class='keuzeDiv' id='".$Keuzescherm['Genrenaam'] ."'>" . $Keuzescherm['Genrenaam']."</div>";}
```

(which produces `<div>...</div>`)

You'll see from my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2Dyu/) that there is nothing wrong with your JavaScript.